# How can the user be informed to move the camera closer to the image direction for improved text extraction?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, google-mlkit

Is there any way to guide customers to come closer to the image or move the camera back from the image to properly scan the data using CameraX and TextRecognizer?